# I just tried KivyMD and stuck with Thai string

Tags: python, kivymd

I just tried KivyMD these are my part of the code

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

teststr= "ทดสอบ"
print(teststr)     #this line can be display thai string to console correctly

mydialog = MDDialog(title= "data",text=str(teststr),size_hint=[0.5,0.5])

mydialog.open()    #this line display wrong string  [some square characters as seen in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQqpF.png)

Comment: Looks like the font in your dialogue doesn't have those characters and can't display them. Not all fonts support the whole Unicode character set.

Comment: Now I avoid using MDDialog and change to MDFillRoundFlatButton and use font_name: 'fonts/THSarabunNew' in my .KV file. By the way, I want to know how to add "font_name" to MDDialog? Can anyone help?